# Mongoose and arrow functions

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am hoping to clear up some of my confusion pertaining to arrow functions and lexical this, my use case with mongoose.

When adding a method to a mongoose Schema, one cannot use an arrow function.
According to this article: https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4
"Lexical Scoping just means that it uses this from the code that contains the Arrow Function."

So if I use an arrow function in a mongoose method, why does 'this' not refer to the schema object, whereas a pre-es6 function does? If the schema and arrow function are in the same file, is the lexical scope not bound to the schema?

Thank you!

```
UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
  const user = this;
  const userObject = user.toObject();
  return _.pick(userObject, ['_id', 'email']);
};
```

Comment: Because arrow functions do not bind this?

Comment: @vp_arth okay I still dont fully follow. According to eric elliot: "Arrow functions don’t bind this. They don’t even have their own this context. In arrow functions, this is always delegated to the lexical context", so if this is delegated, would it not be delegated to the UserSchema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Lexical Scoping just means that it uses this from the code that contains the Arrow Function.

I'll just demonstrate it:

```js
window.answer = 'Unknown'; // `this` equals to `window` in browser (no strict mode)
const object = {
  answer: 42,
  arrow: () => this.answer,
  wrap() {
    const arrow = () => this.answer;
    return arrow();
  },
  stillOuter() { return this.arrow();},
  method() {return this.answer;},
  likeArrow: function() {return this.answer;}.bind(this)
};

console.log(object.arrow(), object.stillOuter(), object.likeArrow()); // Unknown Unknown 
console.log(object.method(), object.wrap()); // 42 42
```

Arrow function's `this` just belongs to outer context.

So, if your arrow functions will be declared inside of correct object, `this` will be correct(almost) too.
Look into that workaround:

```
let tmp = Symbol(); // just to not interfere with something
UserSchema.methods[tmp] = function() {
  this.toJson = data => JSON.stringify(data);
  // All arrow functions here point into `UserSchema.methods` object
  // It will be still `UserSchema.methods` if implementation will copy these methods into other objects or call in the other context
};
UserSchema.methods[tmp]();
delete UserSchema.methods[tmp];
```

Comment: Awesome! This makes sense, thank you. I realize now the UserSchema is an object to which this in a regular function() refers.

Comment: `UserSchema.methods` to be precise